# How to search for users by ID and customData in Stormpath

Tags: stormpath

I'm thinking about using Stormpath with it's Java API as a user storage.

Looks good, except that I can't search for users.

For example, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.stormpath.sdk.resource.ResourceException: HTTP 400, Stormpath 2105 (http://docs.stormpath.com/errors/2105): Account ID is not a supported query property.
```

when I execute this query:

```
HashMap<String, Object> queryParams = Maps.newHashMap();
queryParams.put("ID", "4mPXXXXXXXXXX");
searchResult = application.getAccounts(queryParams);
```

Searching for a user by e-mail however works. I get the same error when I try to search a user by a login-token I stored in the customData property.

It looks like what I want to do is not possible as it looks like the only properties you can query are e-mail and username. But why would they provide this functionality if it didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an impedance mismatch between common relational database behaviors and those in a REST API.   Querying by id, while common in relational databases, is not idiomatic behavior for REST APIs (or most HTTP-based web sites).  The URL (href) is the canonical 'pointer' to a resource on the web.  In other words, in REST APIs, the canonical identifier *is* the href.  Any token inside an href (any internal 'id', special characters, whatever) should be opaque to REST clients and ignored by clients entirely.  URLs are king in HTTP and REST.

That being the case, the Stormpath SDK tries to be true to RESTful best practices, so you can obtain any Stormpath resource by using the `client.getResource` method, which accepts an href and the type of object you expect that href to represent:

```
String href = "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/" + id;
Account account = client.getResource(href, Account.class);
```

That said, there's nothing wrong with wanting this to be more conveniently represented in the client API, for example, `client.getAccount(String id)` if you want to keep the notion of IDs.  If so, please open a new [feature request](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/issues) and we'll be very happy to consider it.

As for queryable `Account` properties, those are [documented here](http://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/#search-accounts).  Stormpath will soon make data in Custom Data searchable as well.  While Stormpath feature timelines are never announced, it is the company's highest engineering priority and it should be out soon.

One workaround that is helpful for some people is to store data they want to search in Account Fields that you don't use in your applications.  For example, you could use the 'middle name' field to store, say, favorite color.  This would only be temporary until custom data search is available.  HTH!

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! :) You are developer at Stormpath?

I'm using a similar workaround. I put my UUIDs into the username field and for the login process, I search the account with the incoming E-Mail, get the username out of it and authenticate against Stormpath. Quite a messy workaround and the latency is between 600ms - 3000ms, but it works and that is ok. 

But I'm looking forward to searchable custom data. That's a kickass feature! :)

Comment: Glad to help!  I'm Stormpath's CTO.  We'll be exposing a 'customId' field on resources sometime soon as well, so you can specify your own unique ID on resources (in addition to the one we specify).  Thanks for your feedback!  (Side note: if the answer is acceptable, could you please award the answer?  Thanks!)

Comment: @LesHazlewood has there been any progress made with the searchable custom data stuff? It would really come in handy for the stuff we are doing, at the moment we are forced to use the `middleName` field for lookups which isn't great :(

Comment: Hey @Les Hazlewood, I had a special case to query stormpath Groups and needed to exclude one of them having a particular name pattern, but stormpath SDK currently doesn't have the NOT operator in it's Criteria APIs... Is this a slip?... or intentional?... and why???

Comment: Just wondering if searching by custom data is now available? I am using C# SDK, and can't find any references to it...

Comment: @Felix it is in beta, please contact support@stormpath.com for access.  Cheers!

Comment: @LesHazlewood The problem with not exposing raw IDs is that, as a customer of your SaaS, I need to be able to reason about Stormpath entities like Account, Group, Organization, etc. by a property that **cannot ever be changed**. Both username and email address are editable fields so If I want to create an application that uses the Stormpath API and I want to link a Stormpath Organization to some concept in my domain model, I cannot do this safely since those properties could be changed by some hapless user in the Stormpath UI. You are now forcing us to parse raw ids out of the href property.

Comment: @AgeMooij, I'm not sure I understand your concern, as Stormpath href's are not editable.